# Completely override a previous git commit

Tags: git

My colleague has pushed to our git repository a mistake. I wish to commit some updated code, but I had not git pulled and as a result am 1 commit behind the HEAD. How can I ignore his changes completely and override his mistake if I am behind?

Comment: first revert to the previous version.  then commit your change.

Comment: Do u have privilege to access the git server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you mean he **pushed** a bad commit to a central repo.

If so, then you can push your version using `git push -f` and this will override the repository. Of course, this will also break history (`f` means *force*) so your colleague(s) will have to re-clone the central repo.

Comment: Your co-worker does not have to re-clone. Just tell him to, 'git fetch; git rebase origin/master', or simply 'git pull --rebase'. After that he needs to fix his commit, or remove it entirely.

Answer (score 8):

You can force a push like the other answer suggests, but a safer way is to go ahead and pull his changes, then `git revert` his commit, which will completely undo all his changes. This doesn't run the risk of unintentionally losing changes:

```
git pull
git revert <treeish naming his commit>
git push
```

Comment: We forgot to add a .gitignore file to prevent adding compiled files, and I'm not quite sure how to resolve merge conflicts.

Comment: If you're using any kind of source control in a team of more than one, I recommend you study merge conflicts before you do anything else. Resolving them is a regular and essential activity. Git has built-in integration with kdiff3, a cross-platform conflict resolution tool. Setting it up would be a good start. I've written a series of articles on Git, and one [walks you through merge conflicts](http://shotgunsandpenguins.blogspot.com/2009/07/journey-to-git-part-v-merging.html). You might take a look.